# write my own memory manager

Tags: c, algorithm, memory-management, memory-fragmentation

I would like to allot some huge dynamic memory and then write my own memory manager for it. i.e. As and when my code needs memory, I'd allot from this pool of memory.  I want the algorithm to take care of internal and external fragmentation.  Which is the most efficient algorithm for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: @Krishnabhadra FAQ says this is on topic: «a software algorithm».

Comment: Read something about [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For these criteria I'd go with Doug Lea's http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html, which maintains collections of blocks of store for each of a number of different sizes - it's quick to find the size you need, and reusing blocks of the same size reduces fragmentation. Note (http://entland.homelinux.com/blog/2008/08/19/practical-efficient-memory-management/) that this is NOT tuned for multi-threading.

If I was writing one myself I'd go for the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation because it's fast and not commonly used in user space (not commonly used because it restricts the possible block sizes, leading to internal fragmentation). In fact, I did, some time ago - http://www.mcdowella.demon.co.uk/buddy.html

Answer (score 1):

This question is amiguous because the term "most efficient" is not clear. You don't say in what terms it should be most efficient.

As an example: There is a strategy called first fit which might be faster than best fit but could lead to more out fragmenetation of the heap (a really bad thing). Best fit on the other hand reduces somewhat the outer fragmentation but still suffers from it while finding a chunk of free memory takes more time. There is also a strategy called buddy heap where you don't suffer from outer fragmentation but from inner fragmentation. But at least finding a free block is usually fast there.

You see choosing an algorithm really depends on your requirements. Should the allocation be fast or the fragmentation low? What's the allocation behavior? Are there small uneven chunks allocated and freed frequently or only big chunks? And there are even more factors playing a role here.

Maybe you wanted an answer like this. If not I recommend you clearify your requirements.

Comment: Yes, best fit, first fit and buddy system are 3 algorithms that can be used each with its own merits and demerits.  The requirement is to have fast allocation and low fragmentation.  Perhaps, I should write in such a way that I call different algorithms in different scenarios.

Comment: @linuxfreak You can do what linux does for example and use buddy heap for getting "bigger chunks" which are in sizes of power of 2 and use something like first fit for smaller chunks. There is also a paper by J.M. Robson ("Bounds for Some Functions Concerning Dynamic Storage Allocation") that proofs that fragmentation problems will not occur if the allocation size is in a certain ratio with the smallest chunk that can be allocated. (of course only the problem of not having enough free space in one chunk to allocate, not the waste of memory due to inner fragmentation)

Comment: @linuxfreak But still the question remains: Can you make assumptions about the allocation behavior? This factor has a great impact on choosing/designing an allocator. Just as an example: If you know that all chunks that are allocated are about the same size you could implement a very fast allocator using a "free chunk list".

Comment: Actually, the allocation size and frequency may vary.  I want the memory allocator to be generic.